Did Kakashi Hatake really obtain one thousand jutsus?
In Naruto, Kakashi Hatake is known as the shinobi who knows one thousand techniques.
My question is, did he really practice one thousand techniques?
If so, how did he manage to achieve that?
I'll appreciate any insights into this.
Thanks in advance!

https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/4dv7ch/kakashi_and_his_supposedly_1000_jutsu/

He knows countless of techniques. Because if I remember correctly, he has copied a lot of techniques with his Sharingan (which is a gift from his comrade, Obito Uchiha). Except for one technique, which is the technique called Chidori, also known as the Lightning Blade.
The chidori part was explained by Guy Sensei here on this episode.
